# Installing Affix on Raspberry Pi

Tags: bluetooth

I'm trying to install [Affix](http://affix.sourceforge.net/) on the Raspberry Pi to use the API and call hci_* functions but I am stuck.

The affix kernel requires the Linux source so I installed it using `apt-get install linux-source` and extracted that inside my `/usr/src` folder.

I then went to the affis kernel directory that I downloaded previously and used `make config`, I set the linux source directory to the one I just extracted and leave everything else default but the config is giving me an error, saying :

[image: make config error]

I checked and the `asm` folder is actually there but its link seems to be linked to a directory that doesn't exist as you can see here (`ls -l`):

[image: ls error]

So, can someone tell me how to properly install Affix on a Raspberry Pi so I can finally continue?

Comment: Is there a reason you need to do this other than you want to use that particular API?  It looks like the maintainer abandoned that stuff *10 years ago*; it may well not work with a 3.x kernel at all.   Is there something beyond semantics this provides that the existing bluetooth stack does not?

Comment: @goldilocks The api offers 'hci_set_pin', I haven't seen any kind of function that does the same for Bluez. I'm trying to connect to a Bluetooth device through Bluez C but I'm getting permission denied when using socket's 'connect' as used in the bluez example because the Bluetooth device requires a PIN and I'm not sure how to send one

Comment: Hmmm...[XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378)?  I know it is a hassle (you'll probably have to use the [LKML](http://www.tux.org/lkml/) or find someone to email directly), but you might want to make sure about the X before you jump to the Y.

Comment: Or maybe it will be much easier than that ;) [How can i set the bluetooth pin number in linux C/C++ ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27632755/how-can-i-set-the-bluetooth-pin-number-in-linux-c-c)

Comment: @goldilocks this seems to answer how to set a PIN for bluetooth devices that try to connect to your device,  I need to be able to send a PIN to a remote Bluetooth device I want to connect to,  me being the client instead of the server as in the link

Comment: Okay.  I don't know much about it, but isn't that pretty much prerequisite for any bluetooth connection?  If so, there *must* be a way to way to do it with the mainstream API.   Keep in mind that's used on a gazillion Android devices, etc.  You'd be much better off asking around about that...it seems almost certain the reason that Affix thing was abandoned is it no longer serves any purpose for anyone.

Answer (score 1):

Try this from the top level of the pi kernel source tree:

```
ln -s arch/arm/include/asm include/asm
```

But again, using stuff across major versions like this is not guaranteed to work.